# EJB not "visible" to EJB manager. Cannot use CDI or JNDI to reference it

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, annotations, ejb, jndi

I have a weird problem that suddenly sprung up when I was trying to create a new EJB and inject it into another EJB so I could call its resources. I'm using Glassfish 3.1, and Java EE 6.

I've done this a couple of times before without problems in the same project, but for some reason this EJB causes deployment errors. As soon as I add the annotation

> @EJB EJBname ejbname;

To the bean I want to reference it in and save I get a deployment server error.

server logs reveals:

> Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.bob.thrift.ThriftClient#com.bob.thrift.ThriftClient not found
>
> javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=com.bob.logic.RSSbean/tclient,Remote 3.x interface =com.bob.thrift.ThriftClient,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.bob.thrift.ThriftClient,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI
>    name used for lookup is 'com.bob.thrift.ThriftClient#com.bob.thrift.ThriftClient' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for...

I don't know what that hash symbol # means or if I can confirm that that is the correct syntax. It looks like that is the correct package where my class exists, however.

I'm doing exactly what I did for the other EJBs they're all simple @stateless session beans. This seems to be analogous to a referenced library file not being listed in the buildpath. As if it has the name but it can't find the actual location. I'm not sure how to resolve this in the case of EJB injection.

Edit:
The EJB with the stuff I need:
    package com.bob.thrift;

```
import com.bob.thrift.sendEventMessage2;
import org.apache.thrift.TException;
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException;

import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Local;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
@LocalBean

public class ThriftClient {

public ThriftClient(){} 

public String sendToServer(String say){
    System.out.println("Entering ThriftClient's main method starting server connection...");
    String msg;
    //**Make Socket**
    TSocket socket = new TSocket("137.222.23.23",1111);

    //**Make Buffer**
    //TSocket bufferedSocket = (socket); skipping this step because the jvm already handles
    //the buffering on this end. 

    //**put in protocol**
    TBinaryProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(socket);
    //**create client to use protocol encoder**
    sendEventMessage2.Client client = new sendEventMessage2.Client(protocol);
```

The EJB with the injection that causes deployment errors:
    package com.bob.logic;

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.bob.eao.XRSSeao;
import com.bob.thrift.ThriftClient;


 @Stateless
 @LocalBean
 //@WebService
public class RSSbean {

private String inputString;
private List Statuses;

@EJB private ThriftClient tclient;
```

As soon as I add the above line "@EJB ThriftClient tclient" it will not deploy and I get NameException, JNDI lookup, mapping null type of exceptions. It refuses to be found this way.

Comment: why is there a dependency on a remote ejb ref thrift client in an EJB? Can you expand on that?

Comment: If the answer below doesn't help, you need to show some more code. E.g. the definition of `EJBname` and the relevant parts of the bean where you're attempting the injection.

Comment: @alphazero it's not remote. It's int he same project, although in a different package but all in the same EJB project in fact. And why I have it like that is just the way my business logic is. I could have probably used a Managed Bean instead but it's just an encapsulation of a business function and I'm calling it from an EJB that needs it.

Comment: @Randnum so 'com.bob.thrift.ThriftClient' is an EJB, and is a (local) dependency of another EJB?  This q needs a bit more detail on your deployment unit.

Comment: @alphazero Yes, It is a LocalBean meaning it exposes a no interface view. I will add both EJB's in the question.

Comment: @Randnum, `@LocalBean` is completely unnecessary here. If your bean does not implement a business interface, it automatically gets a no-interface view. `@LocalBean` is ONLY needed if you want both a local view via a business interface AND a no-interface view.

Comment: Additionally, in code examples, please remove unnecessary fluf like commented out code and debug statements. This makes it hard for other people to quickly focus on the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you did it correctly with your `ejbName`. Suppose you have the following bean:

```
@Stateless
public class MrBean implements MrBeanInterface {}
```

Then you need to inject the bean with `@EJB` annotation as following:

```
@EJB
private MrBeanInterface mrBean;
```

Notice that the class is `MrBeanInterface`, not `MrBean` directly. Alternatively, if you use CDI and you have 2 implementation for the same interface, you can also inject a bean like this:

```
@Stateless
public class MrBean  implements BeanInterface {}

@Stateless
public class MrsBean implements BeanInterface {}

@Inject
@Exact(MrBean.class)
private BeanInterface mrBean;
```

**UPDATE 1:**

This is from [Oracle's tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbnj.html):

- Java EE application clients refer to enterprise bean instances by
  annotating static fields with the @EJB annotation. The annotated
  static field represents the enterprise bean’s business interface,
  which will resolve to the session bean instance when the application
  client container injects the resource references at runtime.

Regarding `What is EJB?`, `When to use EJB?` and `Benefits of EJB?`, you can refer to this [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnblt.html#bnblv).

**UPDATE 2:**

According to your update, your `@LocalBean` does not have any interfaces. This might have violated EJB 3.0's specs. In this [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/ejb30/program.html#wp1208118), they mentioned:

- When using the EJB 3.0 programming model to program a bean, you are
  **required** to  specify a business interface.

Besides, in this [tutorial](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftejb_dvnoview.html) from IBM, they defined a No-Interface Local SessionBean as following:

- The bean does not expose any other client views (Local, Remote, 2.x Remote Home, 2.x Local Home, Web Service) and its implements clause is empty.
- The bean exposes **at least** one other client view. The bean designates that it exposes a no-interface view with the **@LocalBean** annotation on the bean class or in the deployment descriptor.

In brief, I think you should still specify an interface for your `ThriefClient` even if you don't need to use it.

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ThriefClient implements ThriefInterface {
   // Your  functions
}

@Local
public interface ThriefInterface {
   // Empty interface
}
```

Alternatively, in EJB 3.1, you can try this:

```
@Stateless
public class ThriefClient {
   // Your  functions
}

@Stateless
public class RSSbean {
    @EJB
    private ThriefClient thriefClient;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is necessary for EJB 3.  With the no-interface view all public methods are assumed to be local view and declaring the interfaces explicitley is not necessary. So if you call @EJB MrBean mrbean; it's really references the local interface.

Comment: @Randnum: if you called `@EJB` directly on the bean implementation class, it will actually give you errors. Besides, if you really mean it, why don't you just do `private MrBean mrBean = new MrBean();`? Why do you have to use `@EJB` at all?

Comment: Well I am trying to develop a JEE server application. Although I'm new to JEE. I'll admit I do not know WHY an EJB is necessarily required for this, especially since this EJB isn't handling transactions. But I thought if you wanted a class to be managed by the container it had to be an EJB. It's part of my business logic and I do need to reference it in another EJB that my servlets talk to. I'll try your suggestion but I'm not sure what effect on memory and management this would have on the application as a whole.

Comment: @Randnum: I have just updated my answer with more information. Take a look :). Besides, it's actually the right way to do it. You should do things right before caring about efficiency.

Comment: Yes but this is exactly what I did. All you've done is say that I should declare a local interface explicitely when this is not necessary in EJB 3.0 because of the no-interface view. No interface IS the local interface created automatically by the EJB manager. All public methods are put in the interface. This is not a helpful answer. Although what you say is accurate it does not apply to my question.

Comment: Your link points to a JEE 5 tutorial. We're on JEE 6 now. I think you may be unfamiliar with no-interface view and things that are in JEE 6 and EJB 3.0.  I appreciate your help though.

Comment: @Randnum: I have just updated my answer. Hope that it will fix your problem.

Comment: I'll accept your answer only because I think my problem might be unrelated to the original question.  I found that if I commented out the content of the bean the injection worked fine and there were no deployment errors. I still believe you are incorrect that an interface must be created. the No-interface definition that you gave and from my own experience say that it is not required. I will add an interface to see if it changes anything but I do not believe it will.  I have something wrong with the content of my EJB I believe.

Comment: Well :). I will wait for your update then! Who knows if I will run into this same problem someday :P

Comment: I repeatedly see EJB 3.0 being used here, but guys, it's EJB 3.1 that has a no-interface view, not EJB 3.0.

Comment: Since i've already created the EJB without interfaces where should I add the interface class now to test if this works. Can it be anywhere in the project just an interface annotated the same as my EJB with the same functions as my EJB?

Comment: @Randnum: I think you can just create an empty interface in the same package with your bean. It doesn't need to contain any functions.

Comment: @ArjanTijms: haha thanks for the reminder :). I didn't notice this when I was looking for the answer.

Comment: Anyone know if this needs to update the ejb-jar.xml when you create an interface like this?

Comment: hmmm... if you have an interface, I think this `ThriefClient implements ThriefInterface` should be enough?

Comment: I think so, the compiler didn't complain. but Now the server log is saying that it "Cannot Resolve the Reference to the ejb" ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session. I don't know what is going on.  I wonder if me having initially created the project to use a "EJB Client JAR module to hold the client interfaces and classes" somehow became corrupted by me or something I did and now the JAR module isn't being updated properly.

Answer (score 1):

In case others find this question, it's important that you don't think defining an interface is required in Java EE 6 and EJB 3.1. The NO-interface view allows for definitions without interfaces.

Comment: It's true that in EJB 3.1, you don't need interface. However, when you declare the bean, you only need to annotate it with `@Stateless` without `@LocalBean`. If you use `@LocalBean`, you may still need an interface. Besides, you need to be precise about which EJB version you're using in your question. 3.0 and 3.1 may have a number of differences.

Comment: And to satesify anyone's curiousity adding the interface explicitely did not change anything. :) So I have something else wrong. But I'll post that into another question if I can narrow it down any further! What was weird though is all of the Naming and exceptions I was getting that lead me and others on here apparently to think it was the injection mapping or whatever the word is. But that must have just been a side affect of the true problem.